# How to convert TryCast in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to convert following vb code in to c#?

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(address), HttpWebRequest)
```

I tried it using `AS` operator in c# but it is not working.

Comment: When you say it is not working what do you mean? You are getting an error? Can't compile? Returns null? 

Can you clarify?

Comment: `as` is definitely the operator you are looking for. What error are you getting?

Comment: Parse and TryParse are the best options i believe

Comment: @Met - No!  Parse and TryParse are for a different situation (when you have a string and want a numeric object instead); they are NOT equivalent to TryCast and *should not* be used as a substitute for casting. If you don't grasp the difference between parsing and casting, then you should study up on the two topics.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can cast using `as`; this will not throw any exception, but return `null` if the cast is not possible (just like `TryCast`):

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
```

Comment: You can get a default value if the cast is null by using the ternary `??` operator after the `as` statement.

Comment: @Stevo3000: yes, that is also possible (even though the operator you are referring to is the *null-coalescing* operator)

Answer (score 13):

The [`as` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28VS.90%29.aspx) is in fact the C# equivalent:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
Debug.Assert(request != null); // request will be null if the cast fails
```

However, a regular cast is probably preferable:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
```

`WebRequest.Create` should always result in a HttpWebRequest when called with a specific URI scheme. If there is nothing useful to do when the cast fails, then there is no need to defensively cast the variable. If you don't care about the protocol used, then your `request` variable should be of type `WebRequest` (but you lose the ability to check HTTP status codes).

To complete the picture about casts and type checking in C#, you might want to read up on the [`is` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28VS.90%29.aspx) as well.

Comment: Since the question is in context of converting VB to C#, I'll mention that the regular cast you show `(HttpWebRequest)...` is the literal translation of `DirectCast(..., HttpWebRequest)`. Effectively, you are saying that it would have made more sense for the original VB to use `DirectCast` rather than `TryCast`, in this situation.

Answer (score 7):

Simply cast it:

```
HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
```

This will throw an exception if the cast is not successful.

The `as` operator will return a null if the cast is not successful:

```
HttpRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpRequest;
// if cast failed, request == null
```

So, this would be closer to a `TryCast`.

Comment: The only problem with this vs TryCast is that TryCast will return Nothing vs raising an exception if the cast is invalid. Whereas AS will not raise an exception.