# What is the C# equivalance of the Aggregate keyword in VB Linq?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I'm not a big fan of VB. Can anyone help me make this piece of code in c#?

```
 Public ReadOnly Property HasErrors() As Boolean
        Get
            Return (Aggregate o In Me _
                    Let errObj = TryCast(o, IDataErrorInfo) _
                    Where If(errObj IsNot Nothing, errObj.Error <> Nothing, False) _
                    Into Count()) > 0
        End Get
    End Property
```

**Update**

```
Public MustInherit Class MyBaseCollection(Of T)
    Inherits ObservableCollection(Of T)

    Public ReadOnly Property HasErrors() As Boolean
        Get
            Return (Aggregate o In Me _
                    Let errObj = TryCast(o, IDataErrorInfo) _
                    Where If(errObj IsNot Nothing, errObj.Error <> Nothing, False) _
                    Into Count()) > 0
        End Get
    End Property

    Sub New(ByVal query As IEnumerable(Of T), ByVal context As OMSEntities)
        MyBase.New(query)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I've tried to convert it using online code conversion. But I end up with uncompiled code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% on what this is but I think you can do it with

```
this.Any(o => {
  var errObj = o as IDataErrorInfo;
  return errObj != null && errObj.Error != null
});
```

or you can do the more functional style:

```
this.Select(o => o as IDataErrorInfo)
    .Any(errObj => errObj != null && errObj.Error != null);
```

Comment: There is no `TryCast` in C#. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350770/how-to-convert-trycast-in-c

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek ah, I thought that was his own function, in that case we can use `as`

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent for `Aggregate` in syntax-based query in C#. You have to use methods.

```
public bool HasErrors
{
    get
    {
        return this.Select(x => x as IDataErrorInfo)
                   .Where(x => x != null && x.Error != null)
                   .Count() > 0;
    }
}
```

Or easier version with `Count(predicate)` overload:

```
public bool HasErrors
{
    get
    {
        return this.Select(x => x as IDataErrorInfo)
                   .Count(x => x != null && x.Error != null) > 0;
    }
}
```

or even better with `Any(predicate)`:

```
public bool HasErrors
{
    get
    {
        return this.Select(x => x as IDataErrorInfo)
                   .Any(x => x != null && x.Error != null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the exact translation, but it'll get the same result:

```
public bool HasErrors
{
    get
    {
        return this.OfType<IDataErrorInfo>().Any(x => x.Error != null);
    }
}
```